# Play the videos using jquery loops

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, each

I have an array of video urls.

I passed the urls from php to jquery using json.

The script is like this

```
$('.cnt_lsn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var video_dets = JSON.parse($(this).attr('data-video-det'));
    $.each(video_dets, function(i, v){
        console.log(i);  
        console.log(v.vid_url);
    });
});
```

So the value is coming like

```
0
TW51XsixMqA
1
LxRiFFEXs5I
```

Now how can i make the first video play & on clicking next button the next url will be played. I want some logic ideas.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/video.html try this carousel you can bind elements dynamically..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/495/ how about this?

Comment: @ArunChandranC sry its bocked for me...

Comment: @Justcode This is not the slider. The video urls from dynamically. So i need to play one by one on clicking next. So any other suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to achieve this is by using modulo operator to cycle items of array. In your case it can look this way:

```js
var index = 0;

$('.cnt_lsn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var video_dets = $(this).data('video-det'),
        currentVideo = video_dets[index];
    
    // Log current video URL and index
    $('#video').text(index + ': ' + currentVideo.vid_url);
    
    index = ++index % video_dets.length;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="cnt_lsn" data-video-det='[{"vid_url": "TW51XsixMqA"}, {"vid_url": "LxRiFFEXs5I"}, {"vid_url": "HN318SixQqA"}]'>Play</button>

<div id="video"></div>
```

In above demo I simply display URL and video index, in your case you will probably need to set video element `src` and start playing with `play` method instead.

Btw, you can use `$.fn.data` method to read data attribute, it will also parse JSON automatically for you.

Comment: i m using jquery 1.8.3 $.fn.data is not supported think so. Actually i am new to this. How can i do this ?

Comment: It should be supported since 1.4.x. Anyway, itf not just use you current approach with `JSON.parse($(this).attr(...))`.

Comment: I tried your way its saying video_dets not defined. Because i am seeting the attribute by json encoding. SO may be some problem. Then i tried with parsing json still no result.

Comment: Can we do it in php ??